# Checking if a value matches a data type

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to create a program which allows the user to put in a start and finish value and select a data type. If the input matches the data type range the program will count from the start value to the end value and time this, when complete the program will display the time taken.

I am having some difficulty trying to allow only numeric input, decimal input and negative values. I currently have:

```
Private Sub txtInputStart_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtInputStart.KeyPress
    If Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) AndAlso System.Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar) <> 8 AndAlso Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar) <> 45 AndAlso System.Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar) <> 46 Then
        textError.Text = "Please enter numbers, decimals or negative values only"
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

    Private Sub txtInputFinish_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtInputFinish.KeyPress
    If Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) AndAlso System.Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar) <> 8 AndAlso Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar) <> 45 AndAlso System.Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar) <> 46 Then
        textError.Text = "Please enter numbers, decimals or negative values only"
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I am also having some trouble implementing the double data type and decimal data type, I am unsure what how to check if the input fits these data types. What I currently have for data type testing is this:

```
Select Case (cbDataType.SelectedIndex)
        Case 0 'Byte'

            If (lcValueStart < 0 Or lcValueFinish > 255) Then
                textError.Text = "The selected data type Byte can only hold values from 0 through to 255, please reset the form and than try again"
            Else
                Do Until lcValueStart = lcValueFinish
                    lcValueStart = lcValueStart + 1
                Loop
                myTimer.Stop()
                timeValue = (myTimer.Elapsed.ToString)
                lblTimer.Text = timeValue
                MessageBox.Show("Counting success")
                textInfo.Text = "The data type Byte holds values from 0 up to 255 and can be assigned by: Dim varName As Byte = x"

            End If

        Case 1 'UShort'

            If (lcValueStart < 0 Or lcValueFinish > 65535) Then
                textError.Text = "The selected data type UShort can only hold values from 0 through to 65535, please reset the form and than try again"
            Else
                myTimer.Stop()
                timeValue = (myTimer.Elapsed.ToString)
                lblTimer.Text = timeValue
                MessageBox.Show("Counting success")
                textInfo.Text = "The data type UShort holds values from 0 up to 65535 and can be assigned by: Dim varName As UShort = x"
            End If
```

It's easy for these data types since they don't take decimals. Would someone be able to help out here?

Comment: Why would you burden the user with anything to do with *data types*?  There are a great many novice coders who dont completely understand them ( `orderNum = CStr(txtOrder.Text)` )  Also, look into the NumericUpDown and read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: It's an assessment

Comment: Don't try to be perfectly restrictive. Allow multiple negation and period characters, and let the conversion routine handle it. It looks like your input filter should work well enough. What's wrong with it? Although, there's not really any need to display an error on an unacceptable key press.

Comment: There's a bunch of code missing. How you you converting from string to the desired data type? I would use one of the Parse() routines, such as double.TryParse(). Also, see MinValue and MaxValue properties on numeric types, instead of literal values (such as 65535).

Comment: lcValueStart and lcValueFinish are set to the users input from a text box. That code works. I am just confused on how to check their input value if they have selected a double data type or decimal data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't test each keystroke. I would test with TryParse after they have finished entering their input. and clicks an OK button. I assumed you put your DataTypes in a listbox. I have showed you the example of a Double and you can write the code for the rest. I did not include the timer because I wasn't quite sure what you were timing.

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        Dim strStart As String = txtStart.Text
        Dim strFinish As String = txtFinish.Text
        Debug.Print(lstTypes.SelectedItem.ToString)
        Select Case lstTypes.SelectedItem.ToString
            Case "Byte"
            Case "Double"
                Dim dbl As Double
                If Double.TryParse(strStart, dbl) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Your Starting value is within the range of a Double")
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, your Starting value is not in the range of a Double")
                End If
End Select
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Is it possible to place both the strStart and strFinish within one try parse to check if either is not a double?

Comment: No, you will have to write a separate TryParse for Start and Finish. The method can only handle one at a time. If my answer was helpful, please accept it with the check mark (tick mark).

Comment: On second thought, `If Double.TryParse(strStart, dbl) AndAlso Double.TryParse(strFinish, dbl2) Then` Of cours, add another `Dim dbl2 as Double` That second parameter to .TryParse contains the converted number if successful.